# How to make sure that cancelling an Azure Data Factory pipeline terminates the SQL Server stored procedure that it is running?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a number of ADF pipelines that execute an Azure SQL Database stored procedure. I noticed that cancelling an ADF pipeline run (using the 'Cancel Recursive' button in the monitoring pane) does not stop the execution of the Azure SQL Database procedure.
ADF takes a couple of seconds to process a cancellation request, after which it displays the pipeline run as 'Cancelled'. The stored procedure however keeps on running, as is evident by the log rows that continue to be written by the procedure.

How can I make sure that cancelling an ADF pipeline effectively also stops the stored procedure that it is running, as one would expect? Stopping a stored procedure that was started by a pipeline now requires me to kill the relevant process on the server, or to stop and restart the SQL Server database altogether.

I am using the latest versions of Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Factory.

The definition of the pipeline looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "some_pipeline_name",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "some_activity_name",
                "description": "",
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "some_procedure_name",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "fqn_pattern": {
                            "value": "some_value",
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "name_of_some_linked_service_pointing_to_an_azure_sql_database",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "concurrency": 1,
        "folder": {
            "name": "some_folder_name"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2022-07-31T19:56:30Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Comment: How is the pipeline executing the stored procedure?

Comment: The pipeline uses the 'Stored procedure' activity.  
I added the pipeline definition (json) to the question.

Comment: I've also noticed this. The only way I could stop the proc was by running `KILL` in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no direct way to kill the stored procedure if pipeline run is cancelled.**

you can do following workaround:

First, I ran `Stored procedure` activity in **Pipeline 1** to run the stored procedure.

[image]

Then I created another Pipeline **Pipeline2** with `execute pipeline` invoking pipeline 1 and ***`script activity` for the killing the stored procedure if pipeline 1 is cancelled***.

[image]

[image]

**Execution:**

when we are triggering pipeline 2 it will run pipeline 1 also if we cancel the pipeline run It will consider it as failed and will execute the script and stop the stored procedure.

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting approach that deals with the issue in a structural way. Some questions about it:
(1) I don't have the necessary permissions to use `sys.fn_get_sql`. Does the script determine its own SPID, which is assumed to be the same as pipeline2's SPID? If so, I guess I can use SQL Server's @@SPID function instead?
(2) How could this be made scalable so it can be used for dozens of pipelines without having to create an extra script and pipeline for each?
(3) Quid pipelines that use multiple sessions (parallel flows) to SQL Server?

Comment: (1) To generally kill the stored procedure, we have to kill the respective session in which the stored procedure is running to retrieve that I used that script. you can use your own script to kill stored procedure in script activity. (2) I know this is not a scalable option This is just a workaround because there is no built in feature to execute query or stop stored procedure when pipeline run fails.